# matrix of exponentially declining values according to a given vector

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

I have a vector of solar radiation measurements for a water body, I would like to calculate the radiation that reaches certain depths in the water column. This can be calculated from Beer's law, which I have applied for the second depth of my measurements:

```
rad = 1+(30-1).*rand(365,1);
depth = 1:10;

kz = 0.4;
rad(:,2) = rad(:,1).*exp(-kz.*depth(2));
```

How would I apply this to all of the depths specified in the vector 'depth'? i.e. how would I generate a matrix which has 365 rows and 10 columns where each column refers to the radiation that reaches that particular depth.

Comment: is the formula: `a(n) = a(n-1)*exp(k*b(n))` or is it `a(n) = a(0)*exp(k*b(n))` ?

Comment: because if it's the latter, you just need to do `rad2 = rad*exp(-kz*depth);`

Comment: a(n) = a(0)*exp(k*b(n)) where a(0) is the original vector i.e. 'rad'.

Comment: @Rasman: correct, except that you have to use `bsxfun` for the multiplication.

Comment: @Jonas: why? 365x1 matrix multiplied by 1x10 matrix, gives 365x10. Maybe worry about the transverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the decay of radiation due to scattering and absorption is a simple %-loss per depth, you can calculate the result very easily from the initial radiation:

```
initialRad = 1+(30-1).*rand(365,1);
depth = 0:10; %# start with zero so that the first column is your initial radiation

kz = 0.4;
rad = bsxfun(@times, initialRad, exp(-kz*depth) );
```

Note that as @Rasman points out, you can use vector multiplication instead of `bsxfun`, since multiplying a m-by-1 array with a 1-by-n array results in a m-by-n array. The `bsxfun` solution can be more robust, since it also works when the arrays have additional dimensions (e.g. m-by-1-by-k and 1-by-n-by-k if you do multiple tests), or if the vectors are transposed (e.g. 1-by-m and n-by-1). The solution below is a nice demonstration of good linear algebra skills, though you may want to add a note why you don't use dot multiplication with the two vectors `initialRad` and the `exp`-statement.

```
rad = initialRad * exp(-kz * depth);
```

Comment: you need to add exp to your solution... and I still think bsxfun is overkill

Answer (score -1):

You should use loops,

here you can read a tutorial about them, and how to use them,

http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/for.html

basically what you need is, a for loop that contains i as main parameter. Which should run for

```
i=1 .. 9
```

and your main assignment would become

```
rad(:,i+1) = rad(:,i).*exp(-kz.*depth(2));
```

to be more precise

```
for i = drange(1:9)
   rad(:,i+1) = rad(:,i).*exp(-kz.*depth(2));
end
```

I do not know the subject but this function will sweep your matrix, column by column, starts assigning column 2 using column 1 and goes on till column 10.

Comment: Matlab's sole aim should not be just not to write loops, In fact in iterative recursive solutions there is no other way than using loops.

Comment: Loops in general are a poor idea for problems where you don't need them. Worse is when you don't preallocate your arrays if you do use a loop, then cause the array to grow in size. That is quite inefficient. Learn to preallocate those arrays. And learn how to solve problems without use of loops. Your code will improve.

Comment: I'd also note that your "solution" is actually incorrect, since it refers explicitly to depth(2).

Comment: My solution is not a solution, is just a way of how she can use loops, BTW, everything is a poor idea, when you dont need them. I worked with matlab for a long time, I know there are a lot of situations where you cannot escape using loops. In fact, escaping a great asset that a programming language gives you, is just stupidity. I hope it helped clarifying some points.

Comment: The point is that this does NOT require the use of loops, and that your answer suggests that it does. In fact, the use of a loop here as you show it (without preallocation) can be quite inefficient for larger arrays. Sorry, but that is foolishness, pure and simple. Claiming that you have used MATLAB for a long time is irrelevant. Many people have used a tool without ever learning to use it well.

Comment: Come on! you still stuck with my solution. It is simply a code piece, suggesting use of loops. One should remember wise saying:"premature optimization is the root of all evil." -Knuth. BTW, this quote is said just for loop optimizations. The aim here is to show the asker about use of loops may help, In fact I couldnt care less about correctness of my answer, I just wanted to point out a way. First aim of a solution should always be absolute correction not efficiency, yet efficieny should only be considered after problem understood and solved. But my answer is not bothered with both of them.

Comment: Teaching someone to do something that works poorly, and is KNOWN to be poor is simply foolish. You have not even taught the most elementary things about the use of loops. I.e., that you should preallocate. Don't resort to quoting Knuth to cover up your foolishness.

Comment: My point is NOT that you should not teach about loops. Loops are indeed useful things. But that IF you do, you also teach the person how to use them wisely. Preallocation is an imperative on these things. This is where you are wrong. Don't just say that a loop exists, and that this is how one SHOULD solve the problem.

Comment: Teaching someone something with full extends of something, is like "BAAAM", will possibly make the student very very afraid of the thing. My only foolishness it to continue to argue with you about this matter. OK, I accept, you are omnipotent in the area of programming, so forgive me if I  ,in anyway, offended your.

Comment: BTW, you pre optimization boy, you can not escape what Knuth see years before. It is indeed the root of all evil, unless you are working with millions by millions matrix, or gigs of data, your main purpose should be correctly adressing the problem with a solution. Only a fool, optimizes the code not working correctly.